# When does $ab=a$ implies $b=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a ring. If $ab=a$ then what guarantees $b=1$?

For instance, $2\times{\color{red}3}=2\nRightarrow{\color{red}3}=1$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

Also, I know rings have the distributive property. In rngs, does it mean that we cannot write $4+2=2(2+1)$ in $2\mathbb{Z}$? When exactly are we allowed to "factor" in rings or rngs?

Comment: What you want is an *integral domain*. In an integral domain, we have the cancellation law. Namely, if $xy=xz$ and $x\not=0$, then $y=z$. In your case, $ab=a=a\cdot1$ with $a\not=0$ gives $b=1$. Integral domains are usually defined in terms of *zero divisors*, but the cancellation law is an equivalent property. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain

Comment: **Proposition:** An element $a \in R$ is cancellable *if and only if* $a$ is not a zero divisor. Many familiar rings are *integral domains* ($\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for prime $p$, $\mathbb{k}[x]$ for field $\mathbb{k}$, etc.) which means that only $0 \in R$ is a zero divisor.

Comment: $4+2=2(2+1)$ is still true as both are $6$ which is an element of $2\mathbb{Z}$, just as $1=2\cdot \dfrac{1}{2}\in \mathbb Z$.